# Solving indirect relations / many-to-many tables : How to solve this in icCube?

Tags: iccube

I need to create a subdimension in icCube, for example:

I have two dimensions, the dimension Student and the dimension Localization. The dimension Student has a foreign key from Localization  dimension and the fact table join with student dimension. Also I want create a hierarchy in student dimension with attributes from localization dimension.

Example of the model with localization as subdimension :

[image: Example]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: its complicated, can you do an example of the 3 tables ?

Comment: Hey, I updated the question with an example of the sub dimension

Answer (score 0):

You've two options.

**One dimension / two hierarchies**

You would create a table that is the result of the crossjoin of Student and Localization (in the upcoming icCube version we've a join view). You'll use this 
table to create a Dimension Student that has two hierarchies Student and Localization. Check [Exists](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Exists.php) to see implication (it's usually not very important).

With this you only need to link Students to the facts as the relaction between facts and localization is solved through students ( it handles one-to-many too).

**Two dimensions**

You can create two dimension. One for Student and the other of Localization. Both are independent.

To bind the fact to the location we need to use an intermediate mapping structure that can be directly defined in the facts (it's called 'bridge', see Time). The bridge table would be STUDENT, ID_STUDENT, ID, ID_LOCALIZATION, this helps to build a mapping between ID_STUDENT and ID_LOCALIZATION (that might be many-to-many)

[image]

hope it helps